# post application/x-www-form-urlencoded request by using rest assured

Tags: java, rest, api, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I've tried in postman successfully,by adding Header"Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with x-www-form-urlencoded body.Apparently, this was my first time working on rest. Please advise me that below my code is correct or not. Thank You.

```
RestAssured.baseURI = AssignConfig.app.getProperty("RestURL");
        Response request = RestAssured
        .given()
        .config(RestAssured.config()
        .encoderConfig(EncoderConfig.encoderConfig()
        .encodeContentTypeAs("x-www-form-urlencoded", ContentType.URLENC)))
        .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .formParam("login","userName")
        .formParam("password","password")
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? Error?

Comment: in the response, I was getting java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: and status code as 401.

Comment: you are adding contenttype far too may times - just try 
RequestSpecBuilder customSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder();
        r.setContentType(ContentType.URLENC);
given(customSpec).formParam..